# Что происходит с фигурой если у viewBox высота и ширина разная?

Tags: svg

Внизу фигура увеличится т.к. viewBox  меньше viewPort

```html
<svg width='150' height='150' stroke-width='5' style='border: 1px solid red'>
  <symbol id='a' viewBox=' 0 0 100 100' stroke='blue' >
     <circle r="40" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>
  </symbol>
  <use xlink:href="#a" x="" y=""/ >  
</svg>
```

Внизу фигура уменьшится т.к. viewBox больше viewPort

```html
<svg width='150' height='150' stroke-width='5' style='border: 1px solid red'>
  <symbol id='a' viewBox=' 0 0 200 200' stroke='blue' >
     <circle r="40" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>
  </symbol>
  <use xlink:href="#a" x="" y=""/ >  
</svg>
```

Что происходит с фигурой если у viewBox высота и ширина разная ?

```html
<svg width='150' height='150' stroke-width='5' style='border: 1px solid red'>
  <symbol id='a' viewBox=' 0 0 200 600' stroke='blue' >
     <circle r="40" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="" stroke="" stroke-width=""/>
  </symbol>
  <use xlink:href="#a" x="" y=""/ >  
</svg>
```

Comment: Ну это же просто видимая область...

Comment: @Qwertiy если у viewBox width и height одно и тоже число например 200 и оно больше или меньше viewPort будет уменьшение или увеличение фигуры, а если у  viewBox width  = 200 а у  height  будет 100 то ничего не будет ?